# Effective marketing strategies for independent game projects

Tags: marketing

I would really like to hear how other independents generally approach marketing their game with limited resources. I know how critical marketing is since I've seen it first hand on several fronts. I've been part of teams that didn't put an ounce of marketing into their project and didn't come close to meeting expectations. I've also poured a lot of time into visiting forums to discuss our previous title which resulted in minor bumps over time.

I really think [Wolfire](http://www.wolfire.com) is doing some amazing grass roots marketing with the way they are managing their community around their Blog. They've massed a following that is willing to pay (far in advance) them for their game before they finish it to help support them. That's awesome.

But how many people are really willing to divulge such information that early? Should that be a concern? Should I start talking about my next project before I really have anything implemented?

What has worked for you? I would be particularly interested to hear how people approach Apple's iTunes store. I believe we're looking at around 33,000 games on the store these days.

Comment: [Here is an outstanding checklist that somebody put together](http://www.mindjuice.net/2011/01/21/ios-development-marketing-checklist/). This one is a keeper.

Comment: Good question! I'm more prepared to launch an app successfully thanks to the answers here... ... at least I hope so haha

Comment: The answers will definitely help as long as you dedicate the time to it (this is time consuming stuff). I've read a lot of good stuff since my last project but by far the link I just recently posted below is the best.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [Zero Budget Indie Marketing Guide](http://www.devmag.org.za/articles/78-ZERO-BUDGET-INDIE-MARKETING-GUIDE/) is a great read.  Besides that, definitely start building buzz as soon as you have anything to show, and do your best to keep the buzz up.  Demos, trailers, articles, blog posts, whatever you can get to drive traffic and interest.  From what I've heard, paid advertising is not very effective for indie games, so you may want to avoid it.  Focus instead on building organic and genuine interest.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know how effective this idea is (I haven't tried it yet) but for my current project I am going to advertise on Facebook. Let me explain.

Essentially I am going to create a fan page, and run an ad campaign on Facebook. What I figure is I can spend like $30/mo (or what ever you want) for advertising. As people become a "fan" of the page, a lot of other people will see that. So basically, if that $30/mo generates 5 fans *directly*, it could generate 50 fans *indirectly*. I figure I could also do some fun stuff with the fan page such as give away copies, solicit ideas, etc...

Like I said above, I haven't tried this so I don't know if it will work. However, I will let you know in the near future. :)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Make a note to come back and share the results! :)

Comment: So how did it go? Share your results with us?

Comment: going to launch it in Jan1...i'll let you know when it happens

Comment: Already any news on this?

Comment: sadly, plans change and I am still not ready :(  I haven't had 10 minutes to even touch my code base. Don't worry I will finish this and let you know how it goes :p

Comment: I have started the process...we will see how it goes. Wish me luck! http://cdhrdr.com/ShoopFB

Comment: how did you go?

Comment: @RidIculous not great, but you may have better success.

Comment: @Joe Hmm not really :/ Also, I sit at the other end (publishers). I'm trying to find developers who want to advertise/monetize their games...