# Marketing: Angry Birds - How it's done

Tags: iphone, marketing

Why do some apps, like Angry Birds, dominate the market while other cool/fun/addicting apps are never heard of?

I'm trying to figure out the best marketing strategy, or best way to sell an app to mass market.

Does anybody have any ideas or things they noticed about the marketing of major blockbuster apps, like Angry Birds, why they get so popular and stay at the top of charts.

Thanks for any ideas, comments ...

Comment: Nobody who know it will reveal this to you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective marketing strategies for independent game projects](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/489/effective-marketing-strategies-for-independent-game-projects)

Comment: You need to be featured on one of the "home" or "landing" pages of the Marketplace that your app is being sold in. Otherwise, you need to have a name, and get buzz.

Comment: @Notabene In this world are most of people selfish, but there are also exceptions :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Angry Birds matches the iPhone market very well.

- Short gameplay sessions match the phones usage patterns
- High art production values
- Setting/Characters that are appealing to both sexes
- Very simple mechanics that offer mastery potential in time

This make it a game well suited to the platform and it can appeal to the full range of iPhone users. This is important as a lot of sales on the phone from from word-of-mouth recommendations.

Additionally they have followed a very smart plan of regular updates and additions which get people talking about the game again and keeping it in the top of the charts. On iPhone it is absolutely crucial to get your game in the top 25. This is because of the way visibility works within iTunes and on the phone. Particularly with casual users you don't want them to have to search for your game.

Answer (score 8):

With Angry Bird Seasons, they have a really good ploy to keep you playing the game.  They are only releasing one level every day.  This keeps users coming back every day to play the next level.  For the Android market, this is a fantastic idea because that means people are going to be coming back every day to see your ads.

Answer (score 7):

The developer of TrainYard, a game that was second highest on the app store recently posted in depth information on pricing, marketing and strategy that he noticed while competing with angry birds.

Read more here :
http://struct.ca/

Answer (score 5):

Well I agree with `wkerslake`. I think other strategies which matter are visibility of your app. You need to set up a social networking account that can keep tabs on bugs being reported and updated real time. Helps a lot in-situations where people who use the app feel their concerns are being addressed.

From personal experience, we once created a word game app and the dictionary used in our application did not have a couple of words. This made users quite annoyed and we were not aware of the missing words. People sent out screenshots of the issue, and we were glad to resolve the issue in no time. We also incentivise users with previews to new launches, beta launch enrolment and free premium subscriptions. Community around your game will be more than sufficient marketing.

Comment: Just a (hopefully) helpful suggestion, that since answers get sorted based on votes, a reference like "agreement with the above" can quickly become invalid and confusing as posts shift around due to up-voting.  It's probably better to say something like, "I agree with wkerslake's answer," which would be clear regardless of the current ordering of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Having read this [*rumour*](http://goo.gl/fEgzB) I think that investor with money and media/business contacts  may help somewhat.