# Promoting independent iOS games

Tags: publishing, ios, revenue, marketing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are effective marketing strategies for iPhone games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/what-are-effective-marketing-strategies-for-iphone-games)

I'm interested in promoting my latest iOS game.  **What have you done that really helped spread the word**?  Any smaller game review sites that were helpful?  How about publishing?

Comment: related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/489/effective-marketing-strategies-for-independent-game-projects

Comment: also, pretty much identical dupe: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/what-are-effective-marketing-strategies-for-iphone-games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making flash demo and post it on Newgrounds or other flash portals. Make sure you add information about your game. If the flash game is good, then people will buy the app. Otherwise, you can go with traditional promotion by contacting game review or game blog or youtube channels such as rock paper shotgun, wikigames, machinama, IGN etc.