# How to promote my free javascript game?

Tags: marketing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effective marketing strategies for independent game projects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/489/effective-marketing-strategies-for-independent-game-projects)

I created a javascript game for browsers.
Do you know easy ways to promote it?

Comment: This is covered in other questions: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/where-to-advertise-my-game http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/489/effective-marketing-strategies-for-independent-game-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has an excellent advertising network that reaches many very large audiences.  You can do some advertising with it for very low cost that you are in complete control of, and there's no limit to the number of keywords/phrases you can specify that will trigger your ads to appear.

Google AdWords
  http://adwords.google.com/

I suggest starting off with a minimal amount with them, such as $100.00 (or whatever you think seems reasonable), and try to stretch it out over the course of 1-3 months (you can specify the maximum per day with their system).

I've had a few clients experiment with this, and for some it worked out really well, yet for others it resulted in no new traffic or sales.  I've found the staff at Google to be very helpful too.